# Cannot find a differ supporting object ,Async pipe and ngFor problems in angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-template

I have component that takes as input array of objects that should be filtered and displayed in the template.

```
  @Input() inputAddons: Array<InputAddon>;
  addOns: Observable<InputAddon>;
  lblLeftAddons: Observable<InputAddon>;
```

The definition in the class is above.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.addOns = Observable.from(this.inputAddons);
this.lblLeftAddons = this.addOns.filter(function (x){
  return x.pos == 'left' && x.type == 'label'}
);

this.lblLeftAddons.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
}
```

this is the code where i filter the array

in the template i have this code

```
*ngFor="#addon of lblLeftAddons | async"
```

but it doesn't work. I get exception

```
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' in [lblLeftAddons | async in InputText@14:10]
```

Any ideas what i do wrong?

Comment: This looks similar https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6392

Comment: I checked this before my question and i could not find solution. I have no idea why async pipe behaves like this.

Comment: Actually I don't either. Maybe someone else can shed some light on it.

Comment: I don't know if this is your root problem but you have an issue, you are observing an array of objects but you are trying to observe it as if it were an object. change `@Input() inputAddons: Array<InputAddon>;` for `@Input() inputAddons: InputAddon[];` and `addOns: Observable<InputAddon>;` for `addOns: Observable<InputAddon[]>;` and see if it helps

Comment: That's because you're using [`from`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/from.md), which returns one item of your array at a time. That means that when async subscribes it's getting an object, not an array.

Comment: it works when i add .toArray() in `this.lblLeftAddons = this.addOns.filter(function (x){
  return x.pos == 'left' && x.type == 'label'}
).toArray();` but not i get exception `Expression 'lblLeftAddons | async in InputText@14:10' has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '[object Object]'. Current value: '[object Object]' in [lblLeftAddons | async in InputText@14:10]`

Comment: Add `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in your component.

Comment: @EricMartinez thank you it worked. I still have to use .toArray() but it is fine like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it with few modifications on my code.
First i replaced

```
lblLeftAddons: Observable<InputAddon>;
```

with

```
lblLeftAddons: Observable<InputAddon[]>;
```

Observable must return array in order ngFor to work.

And i modified addon observable to return array

```
this.lblLeftAddons = this.addOns.filter(function (x){

 return x.pos == 'left' && x.type == 'label'}
);
```

Also i added `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in my Component definition

Comment: I had the same problem iterating a non-array (*ngFor="#item of items" where items was not an array).